# Retorno de vistas traducidas

Tags: php, laravel

Al momento de realizar las traducciones de rutas, ulizando el paquete `mcamara/laravel-localization`, lo realiza con siguiente funcción dentro de las rutas:

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.about'), function() {

        });
```

Por allí sin ningun problema. Ahora como logro que el me redireccione al siguiente método: `AboutPageController@index` ??

Ya utilicé: `return View::make('about');` y me retorna la vista sin problemas, pero necesito retornar el método del controlador.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas retornar un método del controlador que gestione esa lógica en lugar de usar un [Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348663/7117697), imagino que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.about'), 'AboutPageController@index');
```

De tal modo que ya en tu controlador realizas las operaciones que necesites:

**AboutPageController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // tu código..

    return View::make('about');
}
```

---

Para más información, revisa la sección [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing) de la documentación

Comment: Mil gracias por tu aporte. Ya habia podido resolver como me comentas.